# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with Nulls

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Is there an option to make MySQL's Group_Concat function include nulls?

Consider the following example from my source table:

```
userId, questionId, selectionId
7, 3, NULL
7, 4, 1
7, 5, 2
```

When I query on the selection table with GROUP_CONCAT, I get the following:

```
7, 4=1,5=2
```

I would like to get the following:

```
7, 3=NULL,4=1,5=2
```

For reference, my query looks like this:

```
Select userId, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(questionId, '=', selectionId))
From selection
Group by userId;
```

I also tried adding an IFNULL like this:

```
Select userId, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(CONCAT(questionId, '=', selectionId), 'NULL'))
From selection
Group by userId;
```

but that produced the following:

```
7, NULL,4=1,5=2
```

Note - There is one other complexity that I forgot to include. The selectionId is a foreign key to another table. I use a left outer join to the selection_text table. My real query includes fields from that table (these fields resolve to NULL since the selectionId is null).

Comment: Produced what it should, try IFNULL on selectionId, not on CONCAT.

Comment: But generally speaking- avoid the use of Group Concat!

Comment: @IcedDante can you elaborate why?

Comment: I should not speak to reductively and broadly against it. It's perfectly fine in many contexts. But if using in prod to fetch from several tables that have xToMany relationships it can mask complexity and lead to inefficient queries.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should just `IFNULL` the column that can be `NULL`;

```
SELECT userId, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(questionId, '=', 
                 IFNULL(selectionId, 'NULL')))
FROM selection
GROUP BY userId;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8168f/4).

Comment: Just had this problem. Awesome answer. I have now learned my something new for today :)

Comment: Sadly this demo is no longer available

Answer (score 7):

You should use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` on the `selectionId` value directly:

```
SELECT
  userId,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(questionId, '=', COALESCE(selectionId, 'NULL')))
FROM selection
GROUP BY userId;
```