# SQL Query with more than 1 WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. I want a list of t1.user_name, t3.item_id WHERE user_id = 17 AND stat = 0 OR the row not exist, meanwhile user_id != 17 AND shipped = 1;

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  shipped tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

I managed to list out half the thing I want where user_id != 17 AND shipped = 1, but I cant hide the item_id's if user=17 AND stat=1.

```
SELECT 
t3.user_id AS 'User_ID',
t1.username AS 'Username',
GROUP_CONCAT(t3.item_id ORDER BY t3.item_id ASC) AS 'Item List'
from table3 t3
inner join table2 t2 on t2.id=t3.item_id
inner join accounts t1 on t1.id=t3.user_id
WHERE user_id != 17 AND t3.shipped=1
group by t3.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT('Item_List') DESC;
```

Also, I dont know how to get a row with a value NULL if the user does not have that item, so it doesn't even have a row for it in t3.

User 1 has item_id 1,2,3,4,5 and shipped 6,7,8,9.

User 17 doesnt have shipped 6,7,8,9, but has 1,2,3,4,5.

so the result should look like this:

| User_Name | Shipped |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 6,7,8,9 |

I hope I explained my problem well. :D

Thank you!

Comment: no you didn't, add data and wanted result also to your question

Comment: You should read about `left join` and put  ` stat = 0` in the on clause

Comment: LEFT JOIN isn't enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336022/mysql-group-concat-with-nulls

Comment: i added a result example

Comment: I Believe to achieve the desired output, you can use a LEFT JOIN to join table3 with table2 and table1, and then use conditional logic in the SELECT statement to check for the required conditions.

Comment: I Made a quickly query, try something like this:
SELECT 
  t1.user_name AS 'User_Name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    IF(t3.user_id = 17 AND t3.stat = 1, NULL, t2.item_no)
    ORDER BY t2.item_no ASC
  ) AS 'Shipped'
FROM 
  table2 t2 
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.item_id AND t3.user_id != 17 AND t3.shipped = 1
  JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = t3.user_id OR t3.user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 
  t1.user_name
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(*) DESC;

Comment: This is basic SQL knowledge and usage. Take the time to learn SQL and read up on it here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/. 
As far as I know, Stackoverflow is not "a dba for hire"-site...

Answer (score 0):

First, *but I cant hide the item_id's if user=17 AND stat=1*

It sounds like you're saying, I have two cases; one where the userid is not 17 and another where the userid is 17. You already have the 'not 17' as  `user_id != 17 AND t3.shipped=1`.  Now add your desired 'is 17' case, `t3.id=17 AND t1.stat!=1` with an OR condition:

```
Where (t3.id != 17 AND t1.shipped=1)
   OR (t3.id=17 AND t1.stat!=1)
```

The parentheses are more for readability as the AND operator has a higher precedence than the OR operator and if you left them off you'd have the same logic and the same results.

Now secondly, *Also, I dont know how to get a row with a value NULL if the user does not have that item*

You need to join the table2 to the table3 using an OUTER JOIN to get the users without products.  The difference between INNER and OUTER joins is that inner only includes existing rows while outer leaves all rows and creates NULL values for the missing data.  You also need to rearrange the table order to get the right set of nulls:

```
From table3 t3 Left Outer Join
     table1 t1 On t1.id=t3.userid Inner Join
     table2 t2 On t2.id=t3.item_id
```

But that's not enough.  Your Where clause includes `t3.shipped=1` which will be NULL when there is no product, and won't be selected.  You need to add a third item to your WHERE clause, `t1.user_id is null`, so in full,

```
Where (t3.id != 17 AND t1.shipped=1)
   OR (t3.id=17 AND t1.stat!=1)
   OR (t1.user_id is null)
```

, and that should do it.